# Python change working direcory does not work properly?

Tags: python, sys

Im new to python and are trying to figure out this for hours.. I want to change the working directory with os in my script by using

```
os.chdir("~") # not working.

os.getcwd #--> "/home/pi/Documents"

#I want to change into a subfolder I tried following
"subfolder"
"subfolder/"
"~../subfolder"
"/subfolder"
```

**Tried**:

```
sys.path.append.
```

Comment: Where is "subfolder" located relative to the working directory?

Comment: Tilde expansion is a feature of the shell; `~` is not a directory name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are in the directory **/home/pi/Dokuments** and you want to go to **/home/pi/Dokuments/subfolder**, you might want to try the following:

```
os.chdir(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "subfolder"))
```

Answer (score 6):

In a shell, `~` refers to the home directory of the invoking user (`$HOME`).

`os.chdir` takes a literal directory name as string. So, with just `os.chdir("~")`, you are trying to `cd` into the `~` directory *relatively* (from the current working directory), which does not exist.

You need to use `os.path.expanduser` to expand the `~` to the value of `$HOME` beforehand:

```
os.chdir(os.path.expanduser('~'))
```

Note that, you need to use `os.path.expanduser` for `~user` references as well, which refers to the `$HOME` of `user`.

Comment: While correct for what you've shown, I'm confused if the OP even wants the home directory rather than just another directory and `~` was an example.